# How to generate a byte array from a List<int> in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I am trying to reverse engineer some old code that is undocumented. I have a Base64 string that is converted to a byte array and then converted with the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ToCollection(byte[] bitfield)
{
  for (int ix = 0; ix < bitfield.Length; ix++)
  {
    var i = ix << 3;
    var b = bitfield[ix];
    if ((b & 0x01) != 0) { yield return i + 0; }
    if ((b & 0x02) != 0) { yield return i + 1; }
    if ((b & 0x04) != 0) { yield return i + 2; }
    if ((b & 0x08) != 0) { yield return i + 3; }
    if ((b & 0x10) != 0) { yield return i + 4; }
    if ((b & 0x20) != 0) { yield return i + 5; }
    if ((b & 0x40) != 0) { yield return i + 6; }
    if ((b & 0x80) != 0) { yield return i + 7; }
  }
}
```

This generates the expected list of int eg. new List { 1, 2, 3, 4 }. The task is to add a new value to this list { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, and reverse it through the same code so that it come out as a byte array. I am not very familiar with what the function is doing so have no idea how to reverse it. Here is a sample Base64 string "EjCAZQM=".

Comment: I suggest you start by writing the code, that can convert it back to the original byte array.

Comment: BTW, Do not ask the same question twice!

Comment: How about bitarray in C# ?

Comment: What is "reverse it" mean ?

Comment: The current code takes a byte array and outputs a collection of int. I want to take a collection of int and output a byte array that I can then send through this same function and get back the same list.

Comment: @Cef I don't understand what you mean .. Can you give me a example?

Answer (score -2):

Use BitArray to set bit flag by index.

```
    byte[] bitfield = null;
    BitArray bitAy = new BitArray(bitfield);
    //set idx 0 to true
    bitAy.Set(0, true);
```